# Dynamically creating python modules from directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have set of python files which will be loaded at runtime, what is the best way to dynamical create module, create class instance dynamically and invoked dynamically. I used as below, Is there any issue in running this coded in python web applications which has to serve for multiple requests at same time ?

```py
def load_modules_from_path(module_name, location):
     spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, location)
     dynamic_module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
     sys.modules[spec.name] = dynamic_module
     spec.loader.exec_module(dynamic_module)
     return dynamic_module

def import_from_package():
    location = 'XXXX/__init__.py'
    return load_modules_from_path('sample-module-1.0.0', location)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    module = import_from_package()
    script_clazz = getattr(module, 'SampleScript')
    instance = script_clazz()
    instance.call_method()
```

Comment: It might help to make a [mre] out of what you have already

Comment: There is probably an order constraint about which file to load first.
Put the above sequence in a function, and then call it w/ each file in a way that you can control the order.  You could probably dynamically figure out the order based on  import inspect, but ? an easier first-pass would be to just find an order that works.